# The typeUrl_ and value_ in google.protobuf.Any in the response received by the grpc java client from the server are empty

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, prototype, grpc-java, grpc-go

There is a GRPC call, the server is implemented by golang, and the client is implemented by Java. The response defined by the server contains a google.protobuf.Any attribute. After receiving the response, the client finds that the type_url and value in the Any object are both Empty, meaningful data are all in the unknownFields field, has anyone encountered similar problems?

Our grpc server has been verified without any problems, the following is the code of the java client:

```
package com.yy.shophub.gateway.grpc.proxy.server.examples;

import com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException;
import com.yy.shophub.gateway.grpc.proto.*;
import io.grpc.Channel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder;
import io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ProductClient {
    private final ProductGrpc.ProductBlockingStub blockingStub;

    /**
     * Construct client for accessing HelloWorld server using the existing channel.
     */
    public ProductClient(Channel channel) {
        // 'channel' here is a Channel, not a ManagedChannel, so it is not this code's responsibility to
        // shut it down.

        // Passing Channels to code makes code easier to test and makes it easier to reuse Channels.
        blockingStub = ProductGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    }

    /**
     * Say hello to server.
     */
    public void getProduct() throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {
        BasicRpc.AuthID authID = BasicRpc.AuthID.newBuilder()
                .setChannel("SHIPIFY")
                .setTenant("T001")
                .setUniqueKey("6141c23b3ee6320023d6e674")
                .build();

        ProductRpc.ProductGetRequest grpcRequest = ProductRpc.ProductGetRequest.newBuilder()
                .setAuthID(authID)
                .setProductId("644784a6aaa03b0011fe4a89")
                .setProductType(0)
                .build();
        R.Response response;
        try {
            response = blockingStub.getProduct(grpcRequest);
        } catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }

        if (response.getData().is(ProductRpc.ProductGetResponse.class)) {
            ProductRpc.ProductGetResponse unpack = response.getData().unpack(ProductRpc.ProductGetResponse.class);
            System.out.println(unpack);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String target = "127.0.0.1:20881";

        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(target)
                // Channels are secure by default (via SSL/TLS). For the example we disable TLS to avoid
                // needing certificates.
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();
        try {
            ProductClient client = new ProductClient(channel);
            client.getProduct();
        } finally {
            channel.shutdownNow().awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the proto definition of the server response：

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
package r;

message Response {
  string code = 1;
  string msg = 2;
  google.protobuf.Any data = 3;
}
```

This is the call result, I want to know why there is no value in typeUrl_ and value_, thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kjVu.png)

I want to know why there are no values in typeUrl_ and value_ in the any object under the returned result

Comment: I don't know the answer **but** can you confirm that the Go server is setting the `type_url` (and a `value`)? Perhaps use a known-good client such as [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl). To unmarshal|unpack, the code will need to be able to determine the `value`'s message type which is encoded as `type_url`. I don't know how Java implements the type registry for this process (the documentation should explain this). Is `main` throwing an (`InvalidProtocolBufferException`?) exception?

Comment: I figured it out, the server repackaged a layer of response in the response interceptor, resulting in inconsistent responses defined by the server and the client, so the question I asked appeared, I modified the response definition of the client proto rpc method This problem is solved, thank you very much for your answer